# Is there a list of Media types which are supported by the Google gdata Python client?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gdata, media-type

Silly question, but does anyone know if there is a list of Media types which are supported by the Google gdata (in particular Python) clients?

I can successfully upload .jpg files to my Google Drive using the Media type ;

```
image/jpeg
```

however, if I try and upload an encrypted compressed archive (.tar.bz2.gpg) file instead, then I get the following runtime error ;

```
gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 415, 'body': 'Content-Type multipart/encrypted is not a valid input type.', 'reason': 'Unsupported Media Type'}
```

As can be seen from the error message, I am using the Media type ;

```
multipart/encrypted
```

in this latter case. I assumed this would be a valid Media type, as it seemed to be the most relevant according to ;

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type
```

I also tried uploading a .zip file using the Media type ;

```
application/zip
```

seeing as that Media type is listed in the file gdata/docs/service.py, i.e. ;

```
# File extensions of documents that are permitted to be uploaded or downloaded.

SUPPORTED_FILETYPES = {
  'CSV': 'text/csv',
  'TSV': 'text/tab-separated-values',
  'TAB': 'text/tab-separated-values',
  'DOC': 'application/msword',
  'DOCX': ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.'
           'wordprocessingml.document'),
  'ODS': 'application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
  'ODT': 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text',
  'RTF': 'application/rtf',
  'SXW': 'application/vnd.sun.xml.writer',
  'TXT': 'text/plain',
  'XLS': 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  'XLSX': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  'PDF': 'application/pdf',
  'PNG': 'image/png',
  'PPT': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
  'PPS': 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
  'HTM': 'text/html',
  'HTML': 'text/html',
  'ZIP': 'application/zip',
  'SWF': 'application/x-shockwave-flash'
  }
```

However, I got the same runtime error message which complained about 'Unsupported Media Type'.

The more I look into this, the more I'm beginning to think the problem is with the server side of things - not the client side. Do I need to register files of this type with the server or something similar?

For what it's worth, my method which is responsible for performing the uploading operation is as follows ;

```
def uploadFile(self, filename, mediaType, titleUpload, labelUpload) :

    nameMethod_short = "GoogleDriveConnector::uploadFile"
    nameMethod       = nameMethod_short + " : "


    print nameMethod + "Enter"

    mediaSource = gdata.MediaSource()
    mediaSource.setFile(filename, mediaType)

    self.client.Upload(
        mediaSource,
        titleUpload,
        None,
        labelUpload)

    print nameMethod + "Exit"
```

My immense thanks in advance, for any possible answers and assistance.

Comment: Have you tried with any other media type that is not a container? Does the same error appear woth other media types (e.g. docx)? I am also not sure about your code, since it is slightly different from the sample code in: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Comment: There is a list of MIME types in this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open